# Is any proper analytic subvariety contained in an analytic hypersurface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Suppose $A$ is subvariety of an irreducible complex space(analytic variety) $X$. Is there an analytic hypersurface of $X$ containing $A$?

Comment: Take an open $U\subset X$ such that $W=U\cap A$ is non-empty (thus it is dense), let $P$ be a prime ideal of codimension $1$ in $O_X(U)_{I(W)}$, let $H$ be the closure of the vanishing set of $P\cap O_X(U)$.

Comment: @reuns this doesn't work in the analytic setting, see the [crosspost at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379140/is-any-proper-subvariety-contained-in-hypersurface). To the OP: cross-posting so quickly is frowned upon, and cross-posting without cross-linking is extremely frowned upon.

Comment: @KReiser Tks I overlooked the term analytic variety. This answer looks fine https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36658/276986

Comment: What is your definition of an analytic hypersurface? Is it required to be closed?

Comment: @MoisheKohan https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s40306-017-0214-3.pdf

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am reading above article. The hypersurface in Prop2.7 I think    is not closed. But in general it should be closed.

Comment: @NgChikeung: The answer really depends on this.