# $c_1^2(L)\geq 0$ for a nef line bundle $L\to S$ over a complex surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, line-bundles, 4-manifolds

Let $S$ be a compact complex surface and $L\to S$ a holomorphic line bundle. $L$ is said to be *nef* if $c_1(L)[C]\geq 0$ for any curve $C\subset S$. Is it true that, for nef $L$, we have $c_1^2(L)\geq0$? This is certainly true if we can represent the class $c_1(L) \in H^2(L;\Bbb Z)\cong H_2(L;\Bbb Z)$ (Poincare duality) by a complex curve $C\subset S$, but I can't see whether this is possible or not.

I know that for  an arbitrary closed oriented smooth 4-manifold $X$, any homology class in $H_2(X;\Bbb Z)$ can be represented by an embedded smooth (real) surface. But is the following corresponding statement also true?: For a closed complex surface $S$, any second homology class can be represented by an embedded complex curve.

Comment: Not every second homology class of a complex surface can be realised by an embedded complex curve. For example, generic tori $\mathbb{C}^2/\Lambda$ have no complex curves at all, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36658/39599).